# COMO PUEDO SACAR EL PORCENTAJE DE ESTOS DOS VALORES?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysqli, porcentaje, reporte

Como puedo sacar el porcentaje de estos valores `TotalCostAmountCur` y `TotalSalesAmountCur`, agrupadas con su ProjId en SQL

**Nota: Son 2 tablas diferentes**

```
SELECT 
    TRA.ProjId, 
    TRA.SubledgerVoucher, 
    TRA.TotalCostAmountCur, 
    TVOS.TotalSalesAmountCur
FROM TPS_TransaccionesAsiento_411044 TRA
INNER JOIN CostoTotal_OS_v1 TVOS ON TRA.ProjId = TVOS.ProjId
GROUP BY TRA.ProjId
```

Comment: Porcentaje con respecto a que? y el código está un tanto ilegible, deberían repensar los nombres de las columnas, o usar un alias..

Comment: Se más específico en tu pregunta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.